# Rails capistrano production deployment error: "ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying deploy a rails website with capistrano on Rails 6.

When I run `cap production deploy`, I get the following error at the assets:precompile portion: `ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes`

I generated this key using this command: `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit --environment production`

When I print out the amount of bytes it has with `cat config/credentials/production.key | wc -c` I get 32

I am not sure why the command used for generating this key is 32 bytes and yet Rail expects 16 bytes.

I am not sure what other information is required. I will provide additional information if necessary to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue myself. I regenerated the key and changed what was on the server which has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: First delete your master.key and credentials.yml.enc

Then regenerate a key by:

rails credentials:edit